# c# JSONConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>> returns nulls

Tags: c#, json.net, generic-collections

I am trying to deserialize an HTTPWebRequest response (Json) to a c# object/class, but am having trouble. A collection with 10 instances of the object are returned, and all the objects are null.

Here is the json:

```
[
{
"id":2227,
"user_id":441,
"grades":
    {"html_url":"https://...",
    "current_score":91.26,
    "current_grade":null,
    },
"sis_account_id":"11",
"user":
    {"id":441,
     "name":"Nicholas Bailey",
    }
},
```

Here are the classes:

```
    public class Grade
{
    public string html_url { get; set; }
    public decimal current_score { get; set; }
    public string current_grade { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
public class Enrollment
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public Grade grades { get; set; }
    public string sis_account_id { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
}
public class RootObject
{
    public Enrollment enrollment { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my code:

```
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://(some uri)");

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        string content = sr.ReadToEnd();

        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore;

        var outObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(content, settings);
```

I have been looking at a lot of code on google but have not found a situation that is close to mine. Also, I'm a bit green on generic collections. The code runs fine but in the debugger the "outObject" contains 10 entries, each with an "Enrollment" object that is null.

I also have tried this with json that has well over 10 entries, but it still comes up with 10. But I'm more focused on the nulls at this point (One thing at a time!). For the sake of brevity I have removed several entries in the json, but the main pattern (an enrollment object with a grades object and a user object embedded in it) remains.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you added 'Serializable' attribute to all your classes?

Comment: @AkshayMahajan Json.NET does not rely on the `Serializable` attribute. `Serializable` affects binary serialization.

Comment: for fun just serialize to dynamic and drop the DTO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deserialize to `List<Enrollment>` not `List<RootObject>`:

```
var enrollment = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Enrollment>>(content, settings);
```

The first JSON object in the root array has properties `"id"`, `"user_id"` and so on that correspond to the members of `Enrollment`.  Conversely there is no property `"enrollment"` in the JSON anywhere.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/65LRt5).

**Update**

You asked, *I tried this and now I'm getting an exception "Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Int32'. Path '[0].associated_user_id', line 1, position 165." associated_user_id was removed for brevity but I will add it back into my code. Any ideas?*

Somewhere your data model you must have the following member (field or property):

```
public int associated_user_id;
```

Change this to a nullable:

```
public int? associated_user_id;
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it! Any idea why the debugger lists only 10 objects, not 13 (which is the total)?

Comment: @PeteHesse - sorry, not off the top of my head.  You might want to [ask another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post).  If this one is answered, please do [mark it as such](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow).